# Bash skipping python commands

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7, shell, python-3.x

I have a simple script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
scl enable python33 bash
args=$#
if [[ $args -eq 1 ]]; then
    python script.py 
fi
```

I run the script with command like `bash myscript foo`, but in the current code above, only the command will run `scl enable python33 bash` and for some reason the next if block won't be executed, but if I remove the line `scl enable python33 bash` then the code in the if block gets execute without any problem.

at first I thought the `scl enable python33 bash` was causing the script to exit, but that is not the case, as I can see `python -V` before and after running the script and it works as intended without errors.

For some reason, the `scl enable python33 bash` command and the if block do not seem to belong in the script.

Comment: What does the `scl` command do?

Comment: @AvihooMamka I have python `2.7` that comes by default with CentOs7. So, I installed python 3.3 and `scl enable python33 bash` makes python3.3 the default in the machine, because my `python script.py` the one you see in the question can only run with python 3.3

Comment: Why not running `python3` directly from its location? For example: `/usr/bin/python3.3 script.py` ?

Comment: Mine is located in `/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3` for some reason, but I wanted to use `python foo.py` since If I run the scl comman I can use python, I didn't know why this shell command was not working.

Comment: @ANW Couldn't you supply the full path to python33 instead of only writing "python" in the shell script?

Comment: @jDo well, usually what I do is, run `scl enable python33 bash` and work with just `python` since it is a lot easier, what I don't know is how I can't produce the same thing using shell.

Comment: @ANW I don't know much about centOS or `scl` but what if you `cd` to the directory containing your script as the first thing in the shell script?

Comment: Syntax of scl command: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html-single/1.0_Release_Notes/index.html#sect-Installation_and_Usage-Use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why its not working as you have written it is because you are forking a new bash process, which has the collection activated; and thus your arguments are not being parsed as you expect.

---

The `scl` tool is part of RedHat's [software collections framework](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html-single/Software_Collections_Guide/).

As the normal tool for installing software (rpm) overrides packages at the system level, RedHat provides software collections as a form of "virtual environment" in order to install multiple versions of software packages, directly through RPM. These packages are called software collections and are all installed in `/opt/rh/`.

The syntax of the `scl` tool for activating a package is:

```
scl enable nameofpackage command
```

*You can add multiple packages to the list.*

In your script, all you need to do is replace the Python call with the `scl` line directly, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=$#
if [[ $args -eq 1 ]]; then
    scl enable python33 python script.py 
fi
```

You can read more about the `scl` command at its [documentation reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html-single/Software_Collections_Guide/#sect-Enabling_the_Software_Collection).

Comment: Hmm, that script gives me this error `Unable to open /etc/scl/conf/python!`

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html-single/Software_Collections_Guide/#sect-Enabling_the_Software_Collection) for passing commands; you can also try replacing `#!/bin/bash` with  `#!/bin/scl enable python33 bash` as the first line, just confirm the location of the scl binary, its probably in `/usr/bin` or somewhere like that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with it `/usr/bin/scl` where the scl binary is located, and tried to run the bash script without any result.

Comment: Hmm, I think your answer right, using `scl enable python33 python script.py` though script.py needs to be changed to a full path for it work.